# Configuring Netbeans IDE for c++ in ubuntu environment

Tags: c++, netbeans, ide

I'm a fairly new Ubuntu user and I'd like some guidance on a configuration issue I'm having. I've written a "hello world" app on c++ and simply trying to see whether it compiles. When I hit F6 I'm asked to [image: "Resolve missing native tools"]. What did I miss and can someone direct me to some resources?

Answer (score 0):

I ran `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to download build-essentials that were missing (my guess). I then ran the same project and found `bin/make` folder. After-which,the program compiled successfully.